How can i install Ubuntu Server 24.04 LTS on Dell laptop
How can I install ubuntu server 24.04 LTS on dell laptop and which tool i can use it to create a bootable USB drive.
Your response will be highly appreciated.

Use Startup Disk Creator

Follow the tutorial (I know this is desktop but it's going to be mostly the same): https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview

Try Ventoy. You can load multiple ISO image files, on a single USB flash drive, and pick which ISO, to install
